# Can Winds of Qal Sisma trigger Willbreaker's ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I use [Winds of Qal Sisma](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Winds%20of%20Qal%20Sisma) to prevent damage from a creature, does [Willbreaker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Willbreaker) trigger and let me gain control of that creature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Willbreaker triggers specifically when something "...becomes the **target** of a spell or ability...". Spells and abilities only target if they say "target" (or if they're an aura being cast). Winds of Qal Sisma doesn't say "target", it just prevents all combat damage, regardless of where it came from, so Willbreaker never sees anything that'd cause it to trigger.

Comment: In addition, Winds doesn't even affect creatures directly, it changes the rules of the game for the turn.